# Set application name on stage files on capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my application with the multistage/ext estensions. It works fine when each stage is in different servers. But for one particular proyect I want to deploy two stages to the same server.

For that I need to set a different application name on each server. And that is what isn't working.

I moved the `application` variable to the stage file and define the `deploy_to` variable with lazy loading.

#### config/deploy.rb

```
set :stages, %w(production beta)
set :default_stage, "beta"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

#set :application, "myapp-beta"
set :user,        "deploy"
set (:deploy_to)  { "/home/#{user}/applications/#{application}" }
```

#### config/deploy/beta.rb

```
server "my.server.com", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application,  "myapp-beta"
set :domains,      "beta.myapp.com"
set :branch,       "beta"
```

I get `Please specify the name of your application, set :application, 'foo'` error

Maybe I should be thinking about deploying to a different server, but now I really want to understand why this isn't working.

thanks

Comment: are you deploying production? Do you have :application set for that?

Comment: I tried and reproduced the exact error. This is because your variable application is not getting set. Hence, I assume you are not invoking cap beta deploy:setup. Instead you must be invoking cap deploy:setup or some other generic task without specifying the environment where application variable is defined.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing functionally wrong with your code. As Lavixu mentioned, as long as you specify the stage name when deploying (i.e. `cap beta deploy:setup`, `cap beta deploy`) then the application variable will be recognised.

Answer (score 0):

```
set (:deploy_to)  { "/home/#{user}/applications/#{application}" }
```

Should be

```
set :deploy_to, -> { "/home/#{user}/applications/#{application}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `fetch` to reference other capistrano variables. ie:

```
set :deploy_to, -> { "/var/deploy/#{fetch(:application)}" }
```

Trying to access `application` directly raised a `undefined local variable or method 'application' for main:Object` error.